# C++ Winsock SO_REUSEADDR: accept() not returning socket on connection

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I am completely new to Winsock and have been trying to write a small HTTP server listening on localhost for educational purposes mainly. Currently the server simply returns a web page to whoever connects to it, without parsing any request.

Logically, I must always be listening for new connections on the listening port (I chose 81 here) after I finish with a client and close the connection, so I've googled quite a bit and found that I should probably be using SO_REUSEADDR for this purpose, but maybe I got it wrong. I am using Firefox as the client.

The first connection always goes without a hitch. However, the second time a client attempts to connect, the accept function doesn't seem to accept the connection. On the other hand, I can see that a connection IS established at that time using a utility that watches local ports (CurrPorts). I've looked for hours for a solution and have tried to make the socket non-blocking, but no luck. What did I do wrong?

```
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>
#include <winerror.h>

inline std::string getAddress(sockaddr_in* sin)
{
    std::string res = std::to_string(sin->sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1) + '.' + std::to_string(sin->sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2) + '.' + std::to_string(sin->sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3) + '.' + std::to_string(sin->sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4);
    return res;
}

void acceptTCP(SOCKET& origSock)
{
    SOCKET tempSock = SOCKET_ERROR;
    struct sockaddr* sa = new sockaddr();
    int size = sizeof(*sa);
    while (tempSock == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        tempSock = accept(origSock, sa, &size);
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        if (err != 0 && err != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) std::cout << "\r\n" << err;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in* sin = (struct sockaddr_in*)sa;
    std::cout << "\r\nConnected to " << getAddress(sin) << ":" << htons(sin->sin_port);
    origSock = tempSock;
}

int closeSocket(SOCKET socket)
{
    shutdown(socket, 2); //I've tried using 0
    std::clock_t start = std::clock();
    char buf[1];
    while ((std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC < 5)
    {
        int res = recv(socket, buf, strlen(buf), IPPROTO_TCP);
        //std::cout << "\r\n" << res;
        bool br = false;
        switch (res)
        {
        case 0: br = true; break; //client closed connection
        case -1:
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
        if (err != WSAEWOULDBLOCK && err != WSAEINTR)  //client closed connection
        {
            br = true;
            break;
        }
        else std::cout << "\r\nError on close socket: " << err;
        }
        default: exit(1); //data is being sent after shutdown request
        };
        if (br) break;
        //if (res == -1) std::cout << ": " << WSAGetLastError();
        //else std::cout << ": " << buf;
        //Sleep(1000);
    }
    return closesocket(socket);
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA WsaDat;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &WsaDat) != 0) std::cout << "???";
    while (true)
    {
        SOCKET socket0 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (socket0 == INVALID_SOCKET) std::cout << "Invalid socket!";
        struct sockaddr_in saServer;
        saServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
        saServer.sin_port = htons(81);
        saServer.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = 127;
        saServer.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = 0;
        saServer.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = 0;
        saServer.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = 1;
        int enable = 1;
        if (setsockopt(socket0, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&enable, sizeof(int)) < 0)
            std::cout << "setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed";
        u_long iMode = 1;
        ioctlsocket(socket0, FIONBIO, &iMode);
        if (bind(socket0, (SOCKADDR*)&saServer, sizeof(saServer)) == SOCKET_ERROR) std::cout << "\r\nSocket Error " << WSAGetLastError();
        else std::cout << "Socket bound!";
        listen(socket0, 1);

        std::thread threadConnection(&acceptTCP, std::ref(socket0)); //I use a thread in case I will want to handle more than one connection at a time in the future, but it serves no purpose here
        threadConnection.join();
        std::string content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body><p>test</p></body></html>";
        std::string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: myServer\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: " + std::to_string(content.length()) + "\r\n\r\n" + content;
        std::cout << "\r\n" << send(socket0, response.c_str(), strlen(response.c_str())*sizeof(char), 0);
        Sleep(1000);
        std::cout << "\r\n" << closeSocket(socket0);
    }
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: The listening socket should be created outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: I have tried that also, and the program seems to go into an infinite loop taking all my memory and CPU and the computer crashes...

Comment: So fix the bug that's causing that. But the code above can't possibly work. Also, `strlen(response.c_str())*sizeof(char)` -- seriously?!

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that; I wasn't sure it was a bug or something I did wrong.

Comment: Well... it doesn't really matter anyway hehe

Comment: Also, fundamentally, what is the purpose of this `while` loop? If it's to accept connections, why is it telling some other thread to accept them? What is it supposed to be doing while there's no new connection to accept?

Comment: The idea was for the main thread to listen for incoming connections and then pass them on to other threads that would process them.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to safely place the socket's creation outside the while loop (up to setting the localhost address). What now? I've tried not using the closeSocket function and eliminating the closesocket(socket), but both solutions did not work, generating WSAEINVAL errors on the second accept() call.

Comment: It's probably because of this `origSock = tempSock;`. Also, why don't you call `accept` in the `while` loop if the point of the loop is to accept incoming connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your code should work:

Main function:

1. Open listening socket.
2. Bind it.
3. Call listen.
4. Call accept.
5. Dispatch a thread to handle the socket we just accepted.
6. Go to step 4.

Note that the thread never touches the listening socket.

Comment: I've tried putting the bind, listen() call and setting socket options outside the while loop as well as not trying to close the socket in any way, as you suggest here, but I still get WSAEINVAL on the second accept() loop. Also, how do I not touch the listening socket with the new thread? If I understand correctly, there are then 2 sockets when a connection is established?!

Comment: Right, there are two sockets. One is the listening socket that `main` is using to `accept` new connections. The other is the connected socket that the thread is using to talk to a client. Did you get rid of `origSock = tempSock;`? That's clearly nonsense.

Comment: Make the listening socket private to `main` so that there's no chance of the thread mucking with it. Pass the connected socket to the thread and let the thread close it when it's done with it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know this, the online tutorial I used seems to have been awfully wrong... I tried to but I will try again now knowing this.

Comment: OK! Wow everything finally works! I thought all along there was only one socket and that's what befuddled me! Now it all makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: Nit #1:  `WSAGetLastError()` returns the error associated with the most recent API failure. If you look in `acceptTCP()`, you'll notice you're always calling it after `accept()` (even if the `accept()` succeeds).

Nit #2: Most of what (I think) you're trying to do in `closeSocket()` can be accomplished by enabling the `SO_LINGER` option (with a non-zero timeout) on the socket.

Comment: @keithmo sorry for the late reply, but then would using my closeSocket function be considered OK and safe compared to using SO_LINGER, since I've already written it and it seems to work fine?